# Downloading embedded SVGs with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am writing a Python Selenium scraper that is supposed to download all images from a webpage. The webpage requires you to hover over the element for the image to show up which I have already solved on my own. There are (APNG - animated png) PNG images that the scraper downloads just fine since it pulls the src tag. The fatal issue happens when the scraper gets to an animates SVG that is wrapped in an SVG tag but there is no source link for it. As it appears to me, the image is embedded directly in the code itself. I tried searching for a solution but there is nothing that I found so far that can help me automate this. Everyone just refers to the svg-grabber Chrome addon which seems like a workaround rather than a solution and also can't be automated.

This is the page that I am having trouble with :

https://svgmedia.io/

(You need to hover over an item in the "Direct Limit" column the ones before that use standard APNGs)

How can I download this image as an SVG?

This is a cutout piece of my code that handles the download of the images :

```
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).perform()
        img = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@id='img']"))).get_attribute('src')
        print(img)
        img_request = requests.get(img)
        if img_request.ok:
            with open(item.text + ".apng.png", 'wb') as imgfile:
                print(f"Downloading {item.text}")
                imgfile.write(img_request.content)
        else:
            print("Request failed.")
            input("Press any key to exit")
            exit()
```

Any similar approcha to downloading embedded SVGs?

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    'https://stickers.advaith.io/')


element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located
                                          ((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(),"Act Natural")]')))

element.click()

src = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located
                                          ((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img#img'))).get_attribute("src")

print(src)
opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.addheader(
    'User-Agent', "'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'")
filename, headers = opener.retrieve(src, 'newimage.svg')
```

use urllib.request.URLopener()

Comment: I am not sure if I am missing something but your code is retrieving the "src" tag which the SVG on the webpage does not have and that's the root of the issue. The fact that it is embedded in the code makes it different since you can't just supply a source URL. If I misunderstood how your code works feel free to correct me.

Comment: @541daw35d it is there, you just have to wait for it to populate , use the above codd